# Removing owner entity in one to many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, fetch

I have next question.

There are two entities with bidirectional `@OneToMany` association. For example `Company` and `Employee`. One company may have many employees.
I need to remove certain employee. Ok, I use `entityManager` method `remove`. But! If I used `FetchType.Eager` on `@OneToMany` then nothing happens. But if I used `FetchType.Lazy` it works correctly.

Can you explain it for me? I thought it happens due to in case of using `FetchType.Eager` we explicitly attach Company entity, but if i use method getCompany on employee (when I use `FetchType.Lazy`) before removing it still works properly.

Code example:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1L);
em.remove(employee);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Entities code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

I use hibernate 4.3.6.Final and postgresql 9.3-1102-jdbc41.

Comment: Nothing happens or do you get an error? You should get error, as the employee is still referenced by the company. You need to remove it from the company collection as well.

Comment: I don't get error. I understand it, but why does it work with Lazy loading?

Comment: You need to clarify *what* doesn't work. It isn't removed from the database or something else????

Comment: Right, db stays unchangeable.